# Get unexpected result from: ORDER BY [ColumnName] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Description:** unexpected paging result with `ORDER BY [Column A ] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY.If [Column A ]` have the same value.

NOTE: I use SQL Server 2012 Express

**Condition:**

1. Use expression: `ORDER BY [Column A] ...`
2. [Column A] : all rows have the same value.

**Preproduction:**

**Case 1:**

```
SELECT [Id],[Date]    
FROM [TestDateoffset]  
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
```

Current result:

```
Id   Date 
---------------------------------------
1    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
2    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
3    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
4    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Expected result:

```
Id  Date 
-----------------------------------
1   2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
2   2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
3   2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00 
4   2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Status : PASS

**Case 2:**

```
SELECT [Id],[Date]    
FROM [TestDateoffset]  
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Actual result:

```
Id   Date
---------------------------------------
2    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Expected result:

```
Id  Date
---------------------------------------
1   2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Status : FAIL

**Case 3:**

```
SELECT [Id],[Date]    
FROM [TestDateoffset]  
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Actual result:

```
Id   Date
---------------------------------------
2    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Expected result:

It have to different to:

```
Id   Date
---------------------------------------
2    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

Status : FAIL

The result always be the same if I run OFFSET 1 ROWS, or OFFSET 2 ROWS ,..:

```
Id   Date
---------------------------------------
2    2015-01-24 21:40:30.0441628 +07:00
```

**My question:**

1. Is it a bug ?
2. In case 2, case 3: how does it work? Why I always got 2nd record?

I think the `"order"` process behind `"ORDER BY COLUMN ASC"`  and `"ORDER BY COLUMN ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1"` are different. But I don't know why and what is the rule !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ordering on `Date`, but all dates are equal, so SQL Server can return the rows in any order.

To order on `id` when dates are equal, you could use:

```
ORDER BY Date, Id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
              ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks you for your  prompt reply. So, I have to add `Id` to my ORDER in every paging query to make sure I'll get expected result?.  I don't think it's a good practice!

Comment: And is this a bugs ? Because `SQL Server can return the rows in any order` yes, but at least it must be stable and It must has a rule(order by row key index,..).
For example:  `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` and  `OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` can't  return the same result,logically .

Comment: It's not a bug. You are asking for the first row of an unordered set. SQL Server can give you a random row to satisfy your condition. To limit SQL Server's freedom, you have to be more specific, and specify a sort order that sorts each row in a unique position.